# MVC controller using EntityFramework 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, http-status-code-404

Trying to add a MVC controller with read/write action using EntityFramework. My controller name is UsersController. When i hit add, VS creates a folder named Users and subdirectories like Create, Edit, Index etc.

My Entity-Model table name is Users.

When i try to reach them with links below, i got "The resource cannot be found 404" error.

```
http://localhost:64871/Users <br>
http://localhost:64871/Users/Index<br>
http://localhost:64871/Users/Create
```

---

I can reach links which i created with empty MVC controller option.

```
http://localhost:64871/Home<br>
http://localhost:64871/Home/Test
```

What can be wrong? Should i add some values to my RouteConfig file?

My RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

My userscontroller look like;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Aplatform.Controllers
{
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Users/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(Guid id = null)
    {
        Users users = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (users == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Users users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            users.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Users.Add(users);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id = null)
    {
        Users users = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (users == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Users users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id = null)
    {
        Users users = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (users == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        Users users = db.Users.Find(id);
        db.Users.Remove(users);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are missing a public access modifier before the controller...   Could you show how you controllers look like?

Comment: I added my userscontroller codes to question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into similar situations where the default route doesn't handle a path.  I've added fallback routes to handle these cases.  Try this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Users",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi djpark. I added your sample code to my RouteConfig.cs but no luck, same result. Do you have any other idea? Thank you.

Comment: Hi again. After build project, your solution works. Thank you again djpark.!

Answer (score 0):

After a while a figure out something new. If you have errors in your controller (syntax error.. etc) you can get 404 error. If you clear that errors, 404 will be automatically disappear.